# Mongodb ways of implementing many to many?

Tags: mongodb, relationship

I started reading up on MongoDB (which got me very excited) as I understand one of their flaws is the self explanatory lack of relation. Especially when it comes to large or ever growing on both sides, many to many relationships.

And, as I read around the best way to avoid ever growing arrays inside some document is either try avoiding it by creating buckets of documents and then referencing the buckets (that does not guarantee total prevention of overgrowth). Or to create the both document referencing a third many to many document.

Since I could not found a final answer to this dilemma or at least one the wouldn't be a few years old, could someone explain if this is the dead end (in case the project uses a few big(ever growing) many to many relationships) and I should switch to RDBMS?

Comment: If your data is relational in nature (and your question suggests that it is), then you should not consider mongodb. Excitement about particular piece of tech should not be an important factor in choosing technology for a project. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your **usecase**.

The main question is do you actually know why you want to use MongoDB in the first place? Hopefully, the reason is not because of the trend. RDBMS's are still relevant and have their own usecases. For some applications RDBMS is the way to go for some it isn't.

Now back to your original question about many-to-many relations. As you have already researched there are ways to model those relationships in MongoDB. So that doesn't disqualify MongoDB as a database on its own. For example, to you need transactionality or referential integrity checks when you insert or delete records for those many to many relationships? If the answer to that is yes, then  MongoDB may not be the perfect fit for your case.

Comment: What the main pulls were: the ability to scale, serve content at great speed and yet have the schema's as if in SQL. I received a project to build a social-type site, (nothing related to money) so transactions may not be necessary (although having them would be nice). Coming back, to summaries the performance was the main benefit in this choice, but as mentioned I have a fear that relations later on may become a problem :/

Comment: If you with the exact same schema you probably won't get much performance benefits. Normally you think that you want the exact same schema but in reality you don't. If  you need more details we can help if only you have more details about the particular's of your model. Maybe create another question with the details of the model and we can help you understand if MongoDB is a good fit for your case.

Answer (score 0):

When i first started working on MongoDB this exact question crossed my mind and during searching for the answer i read something very interesting (hope i had the link to that for you, but unfortunately i dont).

think of a real world problem where you have a many to many relation that just keeps on growing ? there may be very exceptional cases of such kind.

lets say many students are registered for many courses. Now a course may be registered by 100 students but for sure a student wont register for 100 courses, so you can simply in the student collection keep a array field for registered course ID's..

let's deep dive and say there are a bunch of super brilliant students who actually registered for 100 courses in such scenario a array field may not be a viable solution. Then ? how about a collection that just have student_id and course_id. This even exists in the RDBMS world too.

so the workarounds available should be enough to find and design an optimized solution for probably the most complex of the scenarios.